# Modern approach to 'on error goto [catch-all] label' in C#

Tags: c#, error-handling, vb6-migration

From my research, this question was asked a lot in the early days of dot net, but IMHO a lot of the responses were a bit snarky and 'thats the way we do it now' style. Lets see if the net has grown up a bit.

Example Circa 1992:

```
Sub Main()
On Error GoTo ErrHand
....Code Here
End Sub

ErrHand:
  ' raise error nicely here inc error no, desc, line & character pos
End Sub
```

Clunky as it was, the 'on error goto [catch-all] label' approach available to VB6 had a use, which was to catch unexpected exceptions and report them. It could report the error number & description, with the module, line number and character position of the exception. Diligent developers would, of course, code for anticipated exceptions and business logic exceptions. The on-error thing was a very useful answer to not having a crystal ball.

My C# buddies tell me to use try-catch, but at the same time they say folk-lore says not to put a big try-catch into each method because that is bad practice.

But when I inquire as to the exact source of the folk-lore there is no answer.

So - what is the 2016 answer for the C# equiv of the VB6 'on error goto [catch-all] label' construct, and why can't I have a standardised try-catch wrapping the contents of each module to effect the same unanticipated exception handling?

Comment: is it considered bad to do a try/catch round everything ? yes, why when it was kinda ok before.. well before we didnt have a number of the things we have now. now we can test for nulls and values in one hit with if (stuff?.somethingelse == blah) so it doesnt barf on nulls, we can check number conversions with tryparse, the rule of thumb now is much more localised tests. Code has evolved and going back to vb6 is like comparing life from 40 years ago.. So much has changed its hard to really compare.

Comment: try { /* ... Code here */ } catch (Exception ex) { ... }.  Direct translation, no worse nor better practice than the VB approach.  As a top-level catch-em-all in a Main() entrypoint it is not a terrible practice, but you'd normally favor subscribing the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event.

Comment: @BugFinder thanks for your thoughts. I am not looking for a lazy solution here - more belt and braces. Exceptions will occur. We work hard to handle those we anticipate as per your comments. As app owner I want the fastest fix when we get an exception in live - that means I need information. That means I have to catch the exception and interrogate it to get as many clues are are available. Hence my question. I chose to mention VB6 as a quick way to set the context. 40 years of MS tool dev does not necessarily mean we are better off.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat I dont disagree, like all things, its hard to judge yesteryears code by todays, similarly if they had seen our code back then they would have thought we were mad.. the biggest problem is vb is not entirely compiled, it was more interpreted, so as a result could give line numbers etc.. you can do an application.onthreadexception - I think covers all the app from the off pretty much, and you could then log the generic barf and maybe use intellisense to grab where the stack was.. but its not like vb.. because its compiled.

Comment: @BugFinder thanks for the further thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't know the nature of the error, what can you sensibly do? Just about the only sensible thing to do is to try to log the error and then shut down - you can't reason about the state of the program, all you know is that it's not what you thought it was.

As such, the best place to handle this situation is in [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) or similar (note that the documentation discusses other approaches which may apply for some specific application models).

That way, you write the code once - not once per *function*. (Unless you're writing small "toy" applications, it's vanishingly rare to write single-threaded applications these days, and the `On Error Goto` pattern would have to, at the least, be repeated for every function that acts as an entry point for a new thread)

Anywhere else, if you're writing a `try`/`catch`, it should be because you have a *specific* strategy for dealing with and *recovering* from the error situation.

Comment: Thanks - will read that linked page and respond. Re 'when you don't know the error what's sensible to do?' I agree but the point is to capture something about the exception so as to have a way to a faster diagnosis and solution.  IMHO as a species we have to accept that there are going to be lapses that result in unhandled exceptions. In this discussion I am less focused on the cause and more on time-to-fix. The causes are handled by other effort but my first point stands - there will be exceptions that are not handled and I want to trap then somehow. This is what 'on-error' allowed.